# Retrieve mp3 from raw folder according to its name in android

Tags: android, listview, audio, adapter, playback

I have a problem with retrieving mp3 file from raw folder according to its name in android. The files are named word_1.mp3, word_2.mp3, word_3.mp3.
I can retrieve string and image but don't know how to do this with audio file.
I have two activities named Main.java and  Subjects.java. There's ListView in Main.java that after clicking on items, according to the position it shows the string and image that are coded for example: subject_1, subject_2 and image_1.jpg, image2.jpg by means of Adapter from string file and drawable folder. My code is shown below:

------------ Main.java ------------

```
Subjects_total_number = global.Subjects_total_number;
    Subjects = new String[Subjects_total_number];
    for(int x = 1; x < Subjects_total_number+1; x = x+1) {
        String this_subject = "subject_" + String.valueOf(x);
        int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(this_subject, "string", getPackageName());
        Subjects[x-1] = getResources().getString(resID);
    }

    setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, R.id.textView1,
            Subjects)); 

    lv = getListView();
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view,
            int position, long id) {                        
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Show_Subjects.class);
            String Subject_number = String.valueOf(position+1); 
            i.putExtra("subject_number", Subject_number);
            startActivity(i);

        }

      });
```

--------------- Subjects.java -------------

***** Retrieving string according to code subject_ from string file ****

```
TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    String stringName_1 = "subject_" + String.valueOf(Subject_number);;
    int resID_1 = getResources().getIdentifier(stringName_1, "string", getPackageName());
    tv1.setText(resID_1);
```

***** Retrieving image according to code subject_ from drawable folder****

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    String imageName = "image_" + String.valueOf(Subject_number); 
    int image_res_ID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageName,"drawable",getPackageName());
    iv.setImageResource(image_res_ID);
```

???? So how to do this with mp3 files and set Adapter for it according to file coded name and after clicking on the fist item of the listview, we have a play button in Subjects.java activity that after clicking it plays word_1.mp3.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you want to play a file from raw folder ?

Comment: You want to retrieve an mp3. Ok. But you did not tell what you want to do with it. What will be the destination?

Comment: Thank you for answering. I want to play mp3 from raw folder according to its coded name like word_1.mp3 and word_2.mp3 that the underscore with number is according to the listview items from 1. When the first item of listview from Main.java is clicked, we go to Subjects.java and there we have image_1.jpg, subject_1 string and play_1.png that after clicking, it plays word_1.mp3.